# Hola, estoy programando con React y Django. Tengo un problema para realizar storage en de la data desde React

Tags: reactjs, django

I have and error to configurate local storage.

code in cartAction.js:

```
import axios from 'axios';
```

import { CART_ADD_ITEM } from '../constants/cartCostants';

export const addToCart = (_id, qty) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/products/${_id}/`);

dispatch({
type: CART_ADD_ITEM,
payload: {

```
    product : data_id,
    name: data.name,
    image : data.image,
    price: data.price,
    countInStock: data.countInStock,
    qty
}
```

})

localStorage.setItem('cartItems', JSON.stringify(getState().cart.cartItems));

}

cartReducer.js

```
import { CART_ADD_ITEM } from '../constants/cartCostants'

export const cartReducer = (state = { cartItems: [] }, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
case CART_ADD_ITEM:
  const item = action.payload
  const existingItem = state.cartItems.find(productInCart => productInCart._id === item._id);

  if (existingItem) {
    return {
      ...state,
      cartItems: state.cartItems.map(productInCart => (productInCart._id === item._id ? item : 
      productInCart))
                  
    }
  } else {
    return {
      ...state, cartItems: [...state.cartItems, item]}
  }

default:
  return state
}
```

}

store.js

```
import{  applyMiddleware} from 'redux'
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';

import { configureStore, combineReducers } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import {productListReducer, productDetailsReducer,} from "./reducers/productReducers";
import { cartReducer } from "./reducers/cartReducer";

const reducer = combineReducers({
productList: productListReducer,
productDetails: productDetailsReducer,
cart: cartReducer,
});


const cartItemsFromStorage = localStorage.getItem('cartItems')
? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cartItems'))
: [];

export const initialState = {
cart: {
cartItems: cartItemsFromStorage,
},
};

const middleware = [thunk];

const store = configureStore(reducer, initialState,
composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware)))

export default store;

error in localhost3000:

bootstrap:27 Uncaught SyntaxError: "undefined" is not valid JSON

at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

at ./src/store.js (store.js:16:1)

at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)

at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)

at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)

at ./src/index.js (productConstants.js:7:1)

at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)

at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)

at startup:7:1

at startup:7:1
```

error in Django console:

```
Not Found: /main.4160ecff14476d1d65f3.hot-update.json

[19/Jul/2023 16:34:04] "GET /main.4160ecff14476d1d65f3.hot-update.json HTTP/1.1" 404 2432

Not Found: /main.4160ecff14476d1d65f3.hot-update.json

[19/Jul/2023 16:34:08] "GET /main.4160ecff14476d1d65f3.hot-update.json HTTP/1.1" 404 2432
```

al realizar la compilacion en React el error es "undefined" is not valid JSON.
y en django es 404 2432.